# Insert Google Analytics Tracking Code by way of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert the GA Tracking Code in a form at Contact Form 7, but it isnt working by the "Additional settings"

```
on_submit: "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Send');"
```

^ ISN'T WORKING On "Additional settings"

I create an ID for the send button of my form to insert the tracking code by Js/jQuery, but i dont know the js code to insert it.

Someone can help me with it or another solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Put GA code in footer and try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to track form use, on a page Analytics tracking code is already installed on, you can attach to either of two events:

`on_submit` (executed when form is submitted regardless of outcome), or

`on_sent_ok` (mail sent successfully). All script must be on one line.

Contact Form 7 expects the format:

```
on_sent_ok: "alert('sent ok');"
on_submit: "alert('submit');"
```

http://contactform7.com/additional-settings/

If you are simply trying to add Analytics tracking code to the page, you are better off modifying the theme template files - either page or footer.

Comment: @LeoAmaral let's see what you've tried? You can edit your question with your code sample(s).

Comment: @LeoAmaral and you are using new Analytics tracking embed code, right? Compare to the tracking snippet at this page: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/